# How to establish a link between entities while creating one of them in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to establish a link between *User* and *Package* entities. When a user creates, it needs to be created with a link to the existing package entity. **User entity holds a package class but not it's id.**

Related *User* entity's code block:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
...

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "package_id")
private Package aPackage;

...

}
```

Several things that I tried:

- Added package id field in request body but that didn't make any connection between them.
- Created a post mapping with multiple `@RequestBody` in order to create User POJO with first `@RequestBody` and access package id with second `@RequestBody`. But as I read from internet, it is not possible to use `@RequestBody` more than once in one mapping.

```
public User addUser(@RequestBody User user, @RequestBody Map<String,Object> payload) { ... }
```

I thought I can use path variables or request parameters but I couldn't be sure about this is the best approach. How to link them in an appropriate way?

Comment: > "User entity holds a package class but not it's id." It looks like there is the source of your problem. You can't link to an existing entity, which you don;t know of.

Comment: So for every connection, should i add two fields? Like packageId and package (class) ?

Comment: imho you only need the class, not the id. But the class itself should maintain its own id. And for a creation its the only mandatory field.

Comment: Oh, now i understand. Thank you so much, that worked :)

Comment: 1 more thing avoid exposing your entity, you controller will change very often, if entity is tied to controller then you underlying database mapping will change which is bad, please use mapstruct for simplicity.

Comment: My entities are not tied to controller, where did this come from? There is service layer between them.